# Left join and filter child element in LINQ

Tags: linq, filter, entity, left-join

I have the following entities:

```
student (
    studentID int,
    name string
)


subject (
    ....
    studentID int,
    passed bit,
    date date
)
```

I want a table to show a list of ALL students and count of subjects that the student can pass in 2012.

Then I create the following linq, but fail.

```
(from x in db.student
     join y in db.subject on x.studentID equals y.studentID into z
 from s in z.DefaultIfEmpty() where s.date.Year.Equals(2012)
     select new { 
        x.studentID,
        x.name,
        SubjectPassCount = y.passed.Equals(true).Count
}).Distinct()
```

Would anyone please help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var results = 
    (from x in db.student
     join y in db.subject.Where(s => s.date.Year == 2012 && s.passed)
       on x.studentID equals y.studentID into z
     select new 
     { 
          x.studentID,
          x.name,
          SubjectPassCount = z.Count()
     })
    .Distinct()
```

Or possibly

```
var results = 
    (from x in db.student
     join y in db.subject
       on new { x.studentID, 2012, true } equals new { y.studentID, y.date.Year, y.passed } into z
     select new 
     { 
          x.studentID,
          x.name,
          SubjectPassCount = z.Count()
     })
    .Distinct()
```

Comment: `Count(predicate)` method is not supported by LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I thought that was fixed in recent versions of EF. In any case I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would more `where` conditions a little bit. You also need `group by` statement to count number of subjects per student.

```
(from x in db.student
 join y in db.subject.Where(s => s.date.Year == 2012 && s.passed == true) on x.studentID equals y.studentID into z
 from s in z.DefaultIfEmpty()
 group new {x, s} by new { x.studentID, x.name } into g
 select new { 
     g.Key.studentID,
     g.Key.name,
     SubjectPassCount = g.Where(gi => gr.s != null).Count()
}).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a navigation property `student.subjects` it could be as simple as

```
from x in db.student
     select new { 
        x.studentID,
        x.name,
        SubjectPassCount = x.subjects.Where(s => s.passed && s.Year == 2012)
                                     .Count()
     })
```

(or `x.subjects.Count(s => s.passed && s.Year == 2012)` which is supported in EF 5 at least).